# What is the Windows Explorer column Due Date for?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-v1607

Granted it is to tell me when something it due, but what file type is it tied to?  I dragged a Microsoft Outlook Task to a folder with the Date Due column, but nothing shows up in the column.  I made sure the Task had not expired or was due yet.  I didn't see any metadata/Details for the file to change as well.

What is the xolumn Due Date for in Windows Explorer?  What is it tied to?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: It serves no purpose within Windows Explorer, it exists, because Outlook is installed.  If a file used that meta-data, it would read it obviously.

Comment: Why: When Outlook is installed those columns are added.  Same as WMP adds various columns for music.  Same reason "has flag" exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for managing many files in future , with deadlines in calendar.
Only useful for some folks who need that sort feature with future deadlines.